# .AspNetCore 8.0.1 Overriding Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, authorization

I am trying to override the Authorize Attribute to implement some custom logic, and after that execute the base function.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
// custom logic
        await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context); 

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, i cannot find the OnAuthorizationAsny Method in the base class, nor any other authorization methods. What am i missing? Thanks a lot

Searching for methods to override

Comment: Generally rather than override the Authorize attribute, you can add policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-8.0